# Empty cache after server side rendering a request in isomorphic app using Apollo GraphQL and React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a little problem with an isomorphic js application and maybe you can help me with this. I followed this tutorial: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/server-side-rendering.html regarding SSR and it basically works just fine. The initial request is rendered correctly, so this is fine. It’s the cache that gives me a headache… Whenever I call `client.extract()` it returns just an empty object, so my perfectly rendered page gets re-rendered as soon as the client code kicks in since the cache is empty. At this point I’m totally clueless as to why that doesn’t work. I even had a look at the Githunt example but the code in question is basically the same in my app, apart from differences in package versions.

The stack I use:

- Docker composition with mongodb, graphql-server and isomorphic app
- Razzle as a framework for the isomorphic application
- Styled components

The package versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.2.5",
    "apollo-client": "^2.3.5",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.4",
    "compression": "^1.7.2",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.9.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "razzle": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-apollo": "^2.1.8",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "styled-components": "^3.3.3"
  }
```

Things I tried to fix the issue:

- Remove styled components
- Use `getDataFromTree` instead of `renderToStringWithData`
- Remove docker composition and running it locally (Mac OS)
- Change package versions to the versions in the Githunt example

The client initialization on the server:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
      ssrMode: true,
      link: createHttpLink({
        uri: 'http://server:5000/graphql',
        fetch: fetch,
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          cookie: req.header('Cookie'),
          origin: 'frontend:5000'
        },
      }),
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
    });
```

On client side the cache works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the issue. The error was that I initialized the client-side Apollo Client inside my App component instead of the client entry point (`client.js` in razzle). So I basically had this structure:

```
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
  <StaticRouter context={context} location={req.url}>
    // <App>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      ...
    </ApolloProvider>
    // </App>
  </StaticRouter>
</ApolloProvider>
```

The inner provider (client-side) intercepted the query, so the server-side provider didn't trigger which resulted (of course) in an empty server-side cache.

I don't know if I am the only one that stumbled across that issue, but if not, I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.
Perhaps you are using apollo-client v3 and use `import { getDataFromTree, renderToStringWithData} from '@apollo/react-ssr';`
Try `import {getDataFromTree, renderToStringWithData} from '@apollo/client/react/ssr';`
It helped me. More information here https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo